# enable hover on a disabled button tailwindcss

Tags: next.js, tailwind-css

I have a disabled button that I'm trying to show a tooltip for on hover.

```
<button className="disabled group relative">
 Save
 <ToolTip
  className="group-hover:block hidden"
  text="Login to save"
 />
</button>
```

The tooltip component is a custom component that is basically an absolute div that is either hidden or visible.

For some reason no matter what I try I'm not able to get the disabled button to trigger a hover event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

update:

adding inline style to the button pointEvents fixed the problem

```
<button 
 className="disabled group relative"
 style={{
  pointerEvents: 'fill',
 }} 
>
 Save
 <ToolTip
  className="group-hover:block hidden"
  text="Login to save"
 />
</button>
```